# PHP variable string in Where clause is empty

Tags: php, mysql, drupal

```
echo "row->name = '$row->name'"; //prints name correctly
```

Name of my field

```
$next_row = db_query("select * from field_data_field_department d join taxonomy_term_data t on d.field_department_tid = t.tid where d.entity_id = $entityID and t.name = '$row->name'");
```

Returns Column not found: 1054 Unknown Column 'Name of my field' in where clause''

If I run the query in MariaDB it works

```
select * from field_data_field_department d join taxonomy_term_data t on d.field_department_tid = t.tid where d.entity_id = 10568 and t.name = 'Name of my field';
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could be is related  to the fact you are accessing an  object

( be sure for avoid sql injection) and try using concat

```
  $next_row = db_query("select * 
          from field_data_field_department d 
          join taxonomy_term_data t on d.field_department_tid = t.tid 
          where d.entity_id = $entityID and t.name = '" . $row->name ."'");
```